# If statement for checking icon data in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, icons

I am wanting an action to happen when a specific icon is pressed. I am currently trying to do it by getting the icon data information and using an if statement:

```
child: new CircleButton(
  onTap: () {
    if(IconData==Icons.control_point){
      print("hello");
    }
  },
  iconData: _iconsDaily[index]
),
```

And I am declaring my icons:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<IconData> _iconsDaily = [
      Icons.shopping_cart,
      Icons.cake_rounded,
      Icons.card_giftcard,
      Icons.control_point,
    ];
```

However `IconData==Icons.control_point` are unrelated types and so I am unsure how to compare these. Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: `_iconsDaily[index] == Icons.control_point`

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to check the `iconData` that belongs to the `CircleButton`, you should do it like this

```
child: new CircleButton(
  onTap: () {
    if( _iconsDaily[index] == Icons.control_point){
      print("hello");
    }
  },
  iconData: _iconsDaily[index]
)
```

Comment: Amazing, I thought I had tried that but apparently not so thank you very much - it works perfectly!

Comment: @ajnabz `IconData` is a type of variable, you cannot compare it to a value of a variable. You can only compare a value to the variable's value. Also take note that the new keyword is not needed anymore. You can remove it.